# почему не срабатывает псевдокласс hover

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

При наведении на `.navbar-list>li` меняют цвет только векторы и задний фон `li`, но сама ссылка остается черной, помогите пожалуйста.

---

Код:

```css
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 486px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 100px;
}

.navbar-list li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 65.67px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s all ease;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.navbar-list li:hover {
  background: #83295E;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

i {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar-list a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 538px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-list">
  <li>
    <i class="far fa-user"></i>
    <a href="#">Профиль</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-journal-whills"></i>
    <a href="#">Курсы</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i>
    <a href="#">Инста-тренер</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-torah"></i>
    <a href="#">Задания</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
    <a href="#">Хочешь бан?</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i>
    <a href="#">Реф.система</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="far fa-life-ring"></i>
    <a href="#">Помощь</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Так вы ей цвет не меняете. Она как была чёрной, так и осталась

Comment: .navbar-list li:hover {
    background: #83295E;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
} почему тогда строчка color:white; работает только на иконки ?

Comment: Посмотрите на последнюю строчку в последнем правиле в вашем css.

Comment: .navbar-list li:hover a - вот так надо

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Код не читал, но вот так работает:

```
.navbar-list a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

А вообще, подсвечивать ссылки при наведении на контейнер - это плохая практика, т. к. могут остаться области, при наведении на которые подсветка срабатывать будет, а сам клик - нет, так что осторожнее.

```css
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 486px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 100px;
}

.navbar-list li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 65.67px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s all ease;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.navbar-list li:hover {
  background: #83295E;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

i {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar-list a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 538px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-list">
  <li>
    <i class="far fa-user"></i>
    <a href="#">Профиль</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-journal-whills"></i>
    <a href="#">Курсы</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i>
    <a href="#">Инста-тренер</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-torah"></i>
    <a href="#">Задания</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
    <a href="#">Хочешь бан?</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i>
    <a href="#">Реф.система</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="far fa-life-ring"></i>
    <a href="#">Помощь</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```